# What other definite integrals can be computed in a manner similar to $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}dx$?

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus, soft-question

The technique for computing $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2} dx=\sqrt{\pi}$ by computing the integral squared using polar coordinates is well known. Are there any other integrals that can be computed in a similar way? My question is intentionally vague--any techniques however tangentially related are of interest!

(EDIT 1: To be more specific, what I am imagining is whether it is possible that some definite integrals appear algebraically out of a computation of a double or triple integral in some coordinate system. Or, if there are some heuristic arguments that this probably impossible. Or if someone has a better imagination as to a computation being similar to the example I gave is also good.)

(EDIT 2: It would also be interesting if someone could example how one might come up with the computation in the original example instead of it being seen as an after the factor sort of thing.)

Comment: You mean $e^{-x^2}$.

Comment: Yes, of course. Thanks.

Comment: You could probably construct integral to be computed this way. I don't know of any famous example, though...

Comment: I don't necessarily care about any famous examples. If you can think of any example, I'm interested.

Comment: I once read an article that analyzed the technique, and concluded this was more or less the only example that could be solved using that trick. Unfortunately, I don't recall the precise conclusion or where I read it.

Comment: I suspected that was the only possible function that worked with this trick! I'd love to see some references.

Comment: How about $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{1-xy}\; dx\; dy = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \; \frac{1}{i^{2}}$?

Comment: Generally speaking, $$n!=\mathcal{G}\left(\frac1n\right)\qquad,\qquad\mathcal{G}(n)=\int_0^\infty e^{-x^n}dx$$

Comment: @ChrisK, care to elaborate?

Comment: @Lucian, isn't that just a u-substitution to the gamma function? I don't see a comparable technique involved. In fact, to show $\Gamma(1/2)=\sqrt{\pi}/2$ one uses the example originally given.

Comment: It can be shown, by using induction or other basic methods, that $$\int_0^1(1-\sqrt[n]x)^mdx=\int_0^1(1-\sqrt[m]x)^ndx=\frac1{C_{m+n}^n}=\frac1{C_{m+n}^m}=\frac{m!\cdot n!}{(m+n)!}$$ which implies $$\frac\pi4=\int_0^1\sqrt{1-x^2}dx=\frac{\frac12!\cdot\frac12!}{(\frac12+\frac12)!}=(\tfrac12!)^2\iff\tfrac12!=\sqrt{\pi\over4}=\frac{\sqrt\pi}2$$

Comment: @Lucian, you have a disguised Beta function in your expression there, and the typical proof I looked up for proving the relationship between the beta function and gamma function uses a change of variables into polar coordinates. I didn't recall the use of them, or make the connection, but the same sort of thing is going on, but it is not exactly the same.

Comment: All factorials of argument $\frac1n$ are connected to geometric shapes of the form $X^n+Y^n=R^n\iff$ $x^n+y^n=1\iff y=\sqrt[n]{1-x^n}$ by the formula $\int_0^1\sqrt[n]{1-x^n}dx=\left(\frac1n!\right)^2:\left(\frac2n!\right)$ . The question would be whether these shapes can be expressed parametrically in a ‘polar’ manner similar to a circle $(n=2)$. A generalization of trigonometric functions, as it were, for $n>2$. Then double-integrate $e^{-x^n}$ along both axes, and use these generalized ‘polar’ coordinates to see if it might yield some interesting new insights, if you are interested.

Comment: @Lucian, I think you should write an answer. I'm interested.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not possess any answers (yet), just these nagging questions and ideas. (Sorry).

Comment: @nayrb : Thanks for accepting my answer.  It looks like you were looking for more than what I gave.  I hope you eventually find it.  Regarding your Edit 1: I have not read the paper, but I saw the author give a talk on it, and he gives much more than heuristic arguments, he gives a real proof.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is essentially the only integral that this trick is good for.  See

http://www.unf.edu/~dbell/Poisson.pdf

Comment: The full citation is Denis Bell, 
Poisson’s remarkable calculation - a method or a trick, *Elem. Math.* 65, No. 1, 29-36 (2010), DOI: [10.4171/EM/136](http://dx.doi.org/10.4171/EM/136).

Answer (score 1):

Apparently others have already done it more than 150 years ago ! The following *Wikipedia* articles about certain two-dimensional and three-dimensional geometric shapes characterized by algebraic equations similar to $X^n+Y^n(+Z^n)=R^n\iff x^n+y^n(+z^n)=1$ contain the mathematical expressions of such generalized polar coordinates: [astroids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astroid) ($2$D), [super ellipses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse) ($2$D), [super formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superformula) ($2$D), [super ellipsoids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipsoid) ($3$D), [super quadrics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superquadrics) ($3$D), [super toroids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supertoroid) ($3$D), etc. They are rational powers of trigonometric functions, whose areas and volumes are expressible in terms of the *Beta* and *Gamma* functions. As usual, my ideas are a century too late, and a buck too short. :-) I hope that you'll find these links useful, and sorry for posting this as an answer, but it was too long to fit into the size of a single comment.

Answer (score 0):

Complex Analysis: Evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{1+x^4}\ dx$

Let $f(z)=\frac{z^2}{1+z^4}$.

$(1) \lim_{\ r\to\infty}\int_{-r}^{r}\ \frac{z^2}{1+z^4}\ dz$

$(2) \lim_{\ r\to\infty}\int_{-r}^{r}\ \frac{z^2}{1+z^4} dz = \int_{c}f(z)\ dz -\int_{c_r} f(z)\ dz$. (notice $z$ is on the real axis)

Here we take $c$ to be the semi circle of radius $r$ and $c_r$ to be the arc of $c$.

$(3)$ By the Estimation Lemma (or M-L lemma) $\int_{c_r} f(z)\ dz = 0$.

$(4)$ Now we can apply a special case of the Residue Theorem to evaluate,  $\int_{c}f(z)\ dz$.

$(5)$ So by R.T,  $\int_{c}f(z)\ dz = \sum Res_{z=z_0} f(z)$.

We can finish up from here, but I don't know about your complex variables background, but yes this is another interesting technique that complex analysis presents you with.

Comment: While this is a wonderful integration technique, I don't see any parallels with the method for computing $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2} dx$.

Comment: The OP said this, "My question is intentionally vague--any techniques however tangentially related are of interest!"